# Async parallel to pass data in object

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

So I'm trying to pass data from two databases to my dashboard view after user gets logged in, however...

1. Don't know if that's the right way of doing.
2. Don't know how to access those two objects that are passed in results.

`router.get("/dashboard", middleware.isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    async.parallel([
            function (callback) {
                callback(null, User.findById(req.user));
            },
            function (callback) {
                callback(null, Instrument.find({}));
            }
        ],
        function (err, results) {
            res.send("all good" + results);
            console.log(results)
        });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
router.get("/dashboard", middleware.isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    async.parallel([User.findById(req.user), Instrument.find({})
        ],
        function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                // handle error here
            } else {
                // results[0] will have user object
                // results[1] will have instrument object
                res.send(results); // sending json to client
            }
        });
});
```